# Facing issue while try to build a Qt Project using CMake and make

Tags: qt, makefile, cmake

I have one Qt Project which one I am trying to build with CMake and make. But I am facing some error while running make -j4 command.

```
Error: CMakeFiles/QtCreator.dir/build.make:89: recipe for target 'QtCreator-prefix/src/QtCreator-stamp/QtCreator-download' failed
make[2]: *** [QtCreator-prefix/src/QtCreator-stamp/QtCreator-download] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/QtCreator.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/QtCreator.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:94: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am using cmake version 3.5.1 Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Note that the text you've shown is simply `make` reporting that there *was* an error when processing the target `QtCreator-prefix/src/QtCreator-stamp/QtCreator-download`: the text of the actual error will be above that somewhere.  Please edit your question to include it.  Also, does running `make` without the `-j4` flag change anything?